# Disadvantages of using ASGI instead of WSGI

Tags: python, django, django-channels

What is the explicit and clear disadvantages of using ASGI instead of WSGI for **HTTP request handling** in Django in general?

I know ASGI is for *asynchronous* tasks, but it can also handle synchronous HTTP requests via `http.*` channels. Is it slower than normal WSGI or is there any unsupported features comparing to WSGI?

One more, to provide both REST API and websocket handling in same project, which way do you prefer and why?

1. WSGI for REST + ASGI for websocket in different server instances
2. WSGI for REST + ASGI for websocket in same machine
3. ASGI for both

Comment: https://medium.com/@pgjones/embracing-asgi-with-quart-introducing-hypercorn-652cb6b269f5 has good ASGI upsides

Answer (score 18):

I think the one major downside you will find is that the ASGI servers are newer and therefore tested less, may have less features, fewer in number, and probably have a smaller community behind them. However, I use an ASGI server (Daphne) for everything and feel that websockets offer so much in terms of user experience that everything will eventually shift to ASGI.

Being able to use asyncio in your code is a major benefit for web programming. Instead of running 10 queries one after the other and waiting for each one to come back, you can run 10 queries at the same time, while hitting your cache and making a HTTP request simultaneously on a single thread.

However, everything you use that does IO needs to use async or you will see worse performance. Additionally, all your developers need to be very careful to never block the event loop by doing blocking IO. Blocking IO in an async context is done using threads which have significant overhead. Running everything on a single thread allows very efficient use of CPU caches. When you use a thread for blocking IO you cause a CPU context switch which invalidates the CPU cache.

Django performs worse with async because the current way the async database methods are implemented are just using `sync_to_async` and using a thread pool.

If you aren't doing any IO you will see worse performance with asyncio from adding every async function to the event loop.

Comment: I can't really confirm that experience. We experienced a major performance impact when switching an WSGI application to ASGI. Without an asynchronous ORM, writing a web socket consumer as a separate service, is annoying better for overall performance. Lastly, WSGI servers don't run requests in a single thread/process.

Comment: There is a similar thread about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73219221/django-uvicorn-poor-performance

Comment: @codingjoe Yeah, Django has terrible performance with ASGI. Anything that is using a thread pool is like with the `sync_to_async` stuff in asgiref is going to lose any performance benefits of ASGI since it will miss the CPU cache.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't do any benchmarking but use both WSGI and ASGI in several project and didn't see any sufficient differences between their performance, so if the Django WSGI performance is acceptable for you then ASGI will work too.

For the REST + websockets API I used ASGI for both. There is no reason to use WSGI if you have ASGI enabled in your project (WSGI works over ASGI).