# Django + uvicorn poor performance

Tags: django, uvicorn, asgi

I'm testing Django asgi performance using two very simple views.
I'm running gunicorn and uvicorn in such a manner:

```
gunicorn core.wsgi --workers=1 --threads=1 --access-logfile=- core.wsgi:application
uvicorn --workers 1 core.asgi:application
```

The views are as follows:

```
def simple_sync_view(request):
    usernames = "Hello World"
    return JsonResponse({'message': usernames})


async def simple_async_view(request):
    usernames = "Hello World"
    return JsonResponse({'message': usernames})
```

Project has no middlewares enabled.
When testing using : `wrk -t10 -c100 -d10s http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/sync/`
synchronous server is always several times faster:

```
  10 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    37.42ms    7.87ms 158.35ms   98.88%
    Req/Sec   271.54     38.28   303.00     79.60%
  26885 requests in 10.01s, 4.87MB read
Requests/sec:   2685.95
Transfer/sec:    498.40KB
```

comparing to uvicorn:

```
  10 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   115.38ms   37.55ms 245.49ms   53.91%
    Req/Sec    88.65     41.14   200.00     74.63%
  8638 requests in 10.02s, 1.40MB read
Requests/sec:    862.49
Transfer/sec:    143.19KB
```

regardless of type of view, sync or async.
So I wonder, is the Django in asgi mode so slow or what ?

Comment: Do you have any more information here?

Answer (score 0):

ASGI frameworks really need to be built from the ground up. Django makes heavy use of `sync_to_async` which spawns a thread to do blocking IO in an async context. `sync_to_async` should be used as little as possible since spawning a thread causes a context switch. Single threaded asyncio applications are fast because they do no context switching.

Additionally, there is overhead from putting every function on the event loop. If your application is CPU bound you will see a performance decrease with asyncio. You are only adding the overhead of adding functions to the event loop. asyncio really only makes sense with IO bound applications where you can use libraries that natively support asyncio.